# Laravel : How do I compare/obtain specific datas from cache?

Tags: php, caching, laravel, laravel-4, polling

In my normal polling Laravel chat app, I will save new messages sent by a user into a **file** cache with the key as a string, getting its value from `date(current_time)` function and the body of the message.

Then, when I want to obtain those messages, I will use the last Poll value `$lastPolled = Session::get('lastPolled')` and compare with the key in the cache. Keys that are greater than the $lastPolled value will have their data to be taken as new messages and appended into the conversations.

Finally, I will update the last polled session value `Session::put('lastPolled',date(Y-m-d H:i:s)`

So, how do I compare $lastPolled with all the keys in cache and get each key's values? Something along the lines of:

```
$latestMessages = array();
foreach(KeysInCache as Key=>value){
   if($lastPolled>Key)
      array_push($latestMessages,Key=>value);
}
```

Thank you!

P.s. bonus points for better suggestions. Oh and I can't use memcache/redis/otherSuperCaches for technical reasons, only file/database cache. :(

Answer (score 0):

Why not try some thing like this by creating cache files based on timestamp or key :

Further details and suggestions on same at : http://evertpot.com/107/

> // This is the function you store information with   function
>   store($key,$data,$ttl) {
>
> ```
> // Opening the file
> $h = fopen($this->getFileName($key),'w');
> if (!$h) throw new Exception('Could not write to cache');
> // Serializing along with the TTL
> $data = serialize(array(time()+$ttl,$data));
> if (fwrite($h,$data)===false) {
>   throw new Exception('Could not write to cache');
> }
> fclose($h);
> ```
>
> }
>
> // General function to find the filename for a certain key   private
>   function getFileName($key) {
>
> ```
>   return '/tmp/s_cache' . md5($key);
> ```
>
> }
>
> // The function to fetch data returns false on failure   function
>   fetch($key) {
>
> ```
>   $filename = $this->getFileName($key);
>   if (!file_exists($filename) || !is_readable($filename)) return false;
>
>   $data = file_get_contents($filename);
>
>   $data = @unserialize($data);
>   if (!$data) {
>
>      // Unlinking the file when unserializing failed
>      unlink($filename);
>      return false;
>
>   }
>
>   // checking if the data was expired
>   if (time() > $data[0]) {
>
>      // Unlinking
>      unlink($filename);
>      return false;
>
>   }
>   return $data[1];
> }
> ```
>
> }